# Java paint program double buffering

Tags: java, applet, awt, java-2d

So I'm working on a paint program in school and now I have to double buffer it. After a week of searching and using tutorials online I am still unable to double buffer my program properly... I have written a double buffer function but then you can't paint anything... When i disable the double buffer you can paint fine but the screen flickers. Please help

(Yes I am aware that some of my code is deprecated and I should fix that)

Code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PaintRun extends Applet
{

    static int posx = 0;
    static int posy = 0;

    static int posxOld = 0;
    static int posyOld = 0;

    static int size = 20;

    static int toolNum = 0;

    static boolean ready = false;

    static Color col =  new Color(120,120,120);

    static Button clear = new Button(0,0,20,'C');
    static Button sizeInc = new Button(20,0,20,'+');
    static Button sizeDec = new Button(40,0,20,'-');

    static Tools tool = new Tools(posx,posy);

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        drawButtons(g);
        detectButtons(g);
    }

    private static void detectButtons(Graphics g)
    {       
        if (clear.detect(posx,posy) == true)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 800000, 800000);
            drawButtons(g);
        }
        else if (sizeInc.detect(posx, posy))
        {
            size+=2;
            drawButtons(g);
        }
        else if (sizeDec.detect(posx, posy))
        {
            size-=2;
            if (size <= 2)
                size = 2;
            drawButtons(g);
        }
        else
        {
            if (ready == true)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawLine(posxOld, posyOld, posx, posy);
                drawButtons(g);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void drawButtons(Graphics g)
    {
        clear.setColor(col, Color.BLACK);
        sizeInc.setColor(col, Color.BLACK);
        sizeDec.setColor(col, Color.BLACK);

        clear.drawButton(g);
        sizeInc.drawButton(g);
        sizeDec.drawButton(g);
    }

    public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y)
    {
        posx = x;
        posy = y;

        posxOld = x;
        posyOld = y;

        ready = true;

        repaint();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean mouseDrag(Event e, int x, int y)
    {
        posxOld = posx;
        posyOld = posy;

        posx = x;
        posy = y;

        repaint();
        return true;
    }

    // Normal Update function

    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        paint(g);
    }

    // Double buffered Update function

    /*public void update(Graphics g) 
    {
        Graphics offgc;
        Image offscreen = null;
        Dimension d = size();

        offscreen = createImage(d.width, d.height);
        offgc = offscreen.getGraphics();

        offgc.setColor(getBackground());
        offgc.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        offgc.setColor(getForeground());

        paint(offgc);

        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
    }
    */
}

class Button extends Applet
{

    int minX; // X coord where the button is drawn
    int minY; // Y coord where the button is drawn
    int maxX; // X size
    int maxY; // Y size

    char letter;

    Color back;
    Color line;

    // Constructor block

    public Button(char desc)
    {
        minX = 0;
        minY = 0;

        maxX = 40;
        maxY = 40;

        back = new Color(255,255,255);
        line = new Color(0,0,0);

        letter = desc;
    }

    public Button(int x, int y, char desc)
    {
        minX = x;
        minY = y;

        maxX = 40;
        maxY = 40;

        back = new Color(255,255,255);
        line = new Color(0,0,0);

        letter = desc;
    }

    public Button(int x, int y, int size, char desc)
    {
        minX = x;
        minY = y;

        maxX = size;
        maxY = size;

        back = new Color(255,255,255);
        line = new Color(0,0,0);

        letter = desc;
    }

    public Button(int x, int y, int sizeX, int sizeY, char desc)
    {
        minX = x;
        minY = y;

        maxX = sizeX;
        maxY = sizeY;

        back = new Color(255,255,255);
        line = new Color(0,0,0);

        letter = desc;
    }

    // Draws the button

    public void drawButton(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(back);
        g.fillRect(minX, minY, maxX, maxY);

        g.setColor(line);
        g.drawRect(minX, minY, maxX, maxY);
        g.drawString(Character.toString(letter), (minX+maxX/2)-4, (minY+maxY/2)+4);
    }

    // Sets the button colors

    public void setColor(Color b, Color l)
    {
        back = b;
        line = l;
    }

    // Detects if those coordinates are in the button location or not

    public boolean detect(int x, int y)
    {
        boolean flag = false;

            if (x > minX && x < (minX + maxX) && y > minY && y < (minY + maxY))
                flag = true;
            else
                flag = false;

        return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be helpful: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/PaintArea.java

Comment: you paint from all kinds of direction and passing the g around will create a chaos - as it does - can you get it together and paint ALL from one single location?? thats my answer

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 3) *"double buffering"* ..is implemented in a `JPanel` by default..

Comment: @gpasch I am unsure of what you mean can you please be more specific?

Comment: @AndrewThompson The text book we are using in class is forcing me to use an applet to make this paint program. This chapter we have to double buffer the paint program because the flickering is annoying. The problem is that the way the book explains it is horrible and it is very hard to learn what I'm supposed to do and what is actually going on in the program.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I looked at this page and I'm unsure at how this will help me... When I tried to run the program i got a slew of errors that I have no idea how to fix because I didn't code the program

Comment: when I asked this I expected someone to actually paste code and explain to help me... not tell me "I'm drawing from all directions"